# emacs: back two lines in function?

Tags: emacs, lisp

I have a function in my emacs dot file to insert a date in my journal. After adding it, I would like to jump back a couple of lines and place the cursor below the date. How do I do that in the function?

```
(defun ddd ()
  "Insert date at point journal style."
  (interactive)
  (insert (format-time-string "[%Y-%m-%d %a]"))
  (insert "\n")
  (insert "\n")
  (insert "\n")
  (insert "** end\n")
  (gobacktwolineshere))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use `save-excursion` to make it more robust:

```
(defun ddd ()
  "Insert date at point journal style."
  (interactive)
  (insert (format-time-string "[%Y-%m-%d %a]\n"))
  (save-excursion (insert "\n\n** end\n")))
```

Comment: Yes, this is probably the best solution for the problem, even if it's not the answer to the stated question.

Answer (score 10):

You want the function `forward-line`, specifically

```
(forward-line -2)
```

goes backward two lines.  For more information, type `C-h f forward-line RET` inside `emacs`.  Depending on where you've left point, you might not end up at the beginning of the line.  If you want this, add a call to `beginning-of-line`.

Answer (score 5):

Remember that if you can tell Emacs to do it interactively (e.g. with <kbd><up></kbd> or <kbd>C-p</kbd> in this instance) then you can ask Emacs what it does when you type that, by prefixing <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>.

In this case, Emacs tells you that those keys run the command `previous-line`, and also:

> If you are thinking of using this in a Lisp program, consider using
>   `forward-line` with a negative argument instead.  It is usually easier
>   to use and more reliable (no dependence on goal column, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

If you know how many characters you want to go back, you can use `(backward-char 9)`.

Comment: This might be a little fragile since it depends on exactly how many characters have been inserted.